# mp4 not playing on website but works on localhost using flowplayer

Tags: mp4, flowplayer

I am trying to play an mp4 using flowplayer.

UPDATE ** It appeared that the files were not being loaded, but the issue is with buffering. The file is loading completely before it plays - so it takes a long time to load the 50mb file. I have added params for buffering in the code below, but I can't get it to start playing without loading the whole file. Help anyone?

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="640" height="360" autobuffer
    data="./flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

    <param name="movie" value="./flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />                                        
    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "./videos/fiddler.mp4", "autoPlay":true, "autoBuffering":true, "bufferLength": 2}}' /> 
</object>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser dev tools for any errors, 404's etc?

Comment: No errors. This is my only log entry: [06:24:24.427] GET http://www.mywebsite.com/fiddler/videos/fiddler.mp4 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK] (note: I've altered the link so it is not valid - but it did point to the correct location)

Comment: Sounds like it could either be permissions on your server or missing files.  Can you show the JavaScript you are using to initiate the player.  Also a screen shot of the Console and Net tab in firebug would help.

Comment: The issue is with buffering. The file is loading completely before it plays - so it takes a long time to load the 58mb and it seemed like it wasn't playing. I have added params for buffering, but I can't get it to start playing without loading the whole file.